# How to format flash drive to FAT32 in macOS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, fat32

When trying to format a flash drive to FAAT32 by using macOS, Bug Sur, Disk Utility only shows the APFS.

Answer (score 2):

Using the terminal:

```
diskutil list
```

you will see something like this:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:      TYPE NAME                SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme    *500.3 GB  disk0
   1:      EFI EFI                  209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:      Apple_CoreStorage        499.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:      Apple_Boot Recovery HD   650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:      TYPE NAME                SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      Apple_HFS Macintosh HD   *499.0 GB  disk1
                    Logical Volume on disk0s2
                    0########-####-####-####-###########
                    Unencrypted
/dev/disk2
   #:      TYPE NAME                SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      FDisk_partition_scheme   *32.0 GB    disk2
   1:               DOS_FAT_32 NO NAME
```

choose the right drive:

```
sudo diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 SDCARD MBRFormat /dev/disk2
```

http://learningthings.info/index.php/2016/06/24/learning-to-format-a-sd-card-as-fat32-using-mac-command-line/

Comment: This worked. Thx. On macOS BigSur. DiskUtil doesn't have Fat32 as an option, but this did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, you have to Delete the volumes. To do that, right-click on the Disk in the sidebar.
[Right click the disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld0xH.png)

Delete the APFS volume and after that you can format the disk to FAT32.

[Read more](https://wordpress.com/post/tharinduwijethilake.wordpress.com/469)

Comment: you save my day